# Kurento 6.5 : Custom module error

Tags: kurento

Today I upgraded my kms to 6.5 from 6.4 and my previously working kurento custom module is not loading into kms anymore.

This is the error which I am getting in the log files:

`27231 [0x00007ff80b28d8c0] warning KurentoModuleManager      ModuleManager.cpp:63 loadModule()  Module /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/kurento/modules/libkmsvadcustomfiltermodule.so cannot be loaded: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libkmsvadcustomfilterimpl.so.0: undefined symbol: _ZTv0_n80_N7kurento15MediaObjectImpl9SerializeERNS_14JsonSerializerE`

Output of `$ dpkg -l | egrep -i "kurento|nice|kms"` :

```
gstreamer1.5-nice:amd64               0.1.13.1~20160530102934.80.gd9ef50e.trusty
kms-core-6.0                          6.5.0.20160530141614.trusty               
kms-elements-6.0                      6.5.0.20160530154355.trusty               
kms-filters-6.0                       6.5.0.20160530155443.trusty               
kms-jsonrpc-1.0                       1.1.1.trusty                              
kmsjsoncpp                            1.6.3~20160530102631.40.gd78deb7.trusty   
kurento-media-server-6.0              6.5.0.20160530172436.trusty               
libnice10:amd64                       0.1.13.1~20160530102934.80.gd9ef50e.trusty
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may need to recompile your plugin with the appropriate headers for 6.5.0. Unfortunately modules are not binary compatible between versions and need to be recompiled when the server changes.

Comment: is there any way by which we can specifically install kms 6.4 ? I am facing some issue with kms 6.5 and my custom module I need to revert back to kms 6.4

Comment: What kind of issues? Please open a different question and let's try to solve them.